# Shortcode wordpress with parameter

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I am creating a  wordpress shortcode **[ADD_POT ID='X']**, which is able to get the ID value, in purpose to execute a function.

Unfortunately, there is an error within the third line of my code. Someone can give me a hand please ? Thank you.

```
function ADD_POT($atts) {
    $ID = shortcode_atts(array( 'ID' => TRUE), $atts) ;
    $pot_ID = $ID['ID'] ;
    include dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../wp-config.php' ;
    include dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../wp-content/plugins/Study-Tool/core/login.php' ;
    $pot_selection = "SELECT question_ID FROM questions WHERE pot_ID='$pot_ID'" ;
    $pot_result = mysqli_query ($connect,$pot_selection) ;
    foreach ($pot_result as $pot_ID) {
        $question_ID = $pot_ID['question_ID'] ;
        ADD_Q($question_ID) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: For have some fun

Comment: The real reason is because i need login for in purpose to use a complexe script, hide in ADD_Q

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't know that. Thank you.

Comment: I put the shortcode into my post, but nothing appear :/

Comment: Error in 3rd line means you are having issue on $pot_ID = $ID['ID'];, right?

If yes than can you please check whether you are getting value in $atts value or not?

Comment: Very bad idea to use relative link and include once again the wp-config.php. If you want to query and use sql query you only need to add global $wpdb; at the top of the function, and use plugins_url() (if your running this in a plugin) and get_stylesheet_uri() (for a theme) to include any file.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I had more information. I replace ('ID'=> TRUE) by ('ID'=> '2'), and $pot_ID becomming 2. But the problem is I need to take the value into the post's shortcode ( like [ADD_POT ID='44'] ), not the '2'.. Someone have a idea please ?

Comment: Thank you for your advise Benoti. I take it in my consideration.

Answer (score 1):

Value in this line means default value your ID field have if user has not supplied a value.

$ID = shortcode_atts(array( 'ID' => TRUE), $atts) ;

You need to enclose values in '' in this line for example something like

$ID = shortcode_atts(array( 'ID' => ''), $atts) ;

if you want to have blank as default value. For any other value use the value but in quotes. If user gives a value in input then that value will be used instead of blanks or default value you give here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Esha, but the real problem is, my function don't use the value given by the user in a post like  [ADD_POT ID='X'], instead of the defaut value placed in the array :/

Comment: Someone else have an idea please ?

Answer (score 1):

I solve the problem. It was because I used uppercase instead of lowercase in my wordpress balise.

`[POT_ID **id**=4]`

```
function ADD_POT($atts) {
    $ID = shortcode_atts(array( '**id**' => '1'), $atts);
    $pot_ID = $ID['**id**'];
}
```